# Inserting toggle switch in notification bar

Tags: android

I am doing a project using Android studio. I need a "Toggle Switch in notification bar".

Is it possible insert toggle switch in notification bar?
If yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no offical (and probably no private, too) api to add application-related ui components to the status bar (which I assume you mean by notification bar. You could give your notifications an icon that looks like a toggle, but the user cannot interact with it. The notification itself is customizable to a large degree.